# Apache Reverse Proxy and Virtual Host at the Same Time

Tags: apache, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a VPS with single IP. The VPS should serve 3 websites. Site1 - www.domain.com via WordPress. Site2 - sub.domain.com via WordPress. Site3 - anothersub.domain.com via NodeJS inside of a Docker container that listens on port 81. Site1 and Site2 are pretty straight forward, just need to set up virtual hosts. But, how do I set up Apache for Site3? Could you provide an example or correct syntax, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from apache docs (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#proxy)

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://192.168.111.2/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.111.2/"
    ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and for your case :

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass        "/" "http://localhost:81/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:81/"
        ServerName hostname.example.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, very much! Apache docs are very confusing for a novice.